# Добавление Recaptha в приложение PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, recaptcha

Можно ли добавить `recaptha` как у *Google* или что-то похожее в PyQt5 приложение?

Можно, пожалуйста, пример как это сделать?

[image: пример]

**primermain.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from primer import Ui_MainWindow


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**primer.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1330, 546)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 20, 400, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 320, 341, 81))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ПРОВЕРКА НА РОБОТА"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
```

---

Хочу сделать что-то похожее:

[image: Пример]

Comment: Я не совсем понял, что вы хотите сделать.
У вас есть клиентская и серверная сторона? Объясните пожалуйста лучше.

Comment: У меня есть приложение, куда я хочу добавить проверку на робота.

Comment: Ваше приложение на какой стороне находится ?  Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимально-воспроизводимый пример вашего приложения.

Comment: @S. Nick Сделал окно для примера, добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То что вы хотите сделать, это не совсем `recaptcha`.

Что-то похожее может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import * 
import random


class ExampleApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.dbFamilies = ['Brush Script MT', 'Chiller']
        self.rand_int, self.rand_choi = ..., ...

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        button_1 = QPushButton("Обновить выражение", clicked=self.refresh)
        button_2 = QPushButton("Проверить результат", clicked=self.result)

        grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(button_1, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(button_2, 1, 1)
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        family = random.choice(self.dbFamilies)
        self.rand_int = [random.randint(1, 20) for _ in range(2)]
        self.rand_choi = random.choice(['+', '-', '*'])
        self.label.setFont(QFont("{}".format(family), 72))
        self.label.setText('{}{}{}=?'.format(self.rand_int[0], self.rand_choi, self.rand_int[1]))
        self.label.adjustSize()        
        self.lineEdit.clear()

    def result(self):
        if self.rand_choi   == '+': r = self.rand_int[0] + self.rand_int[1]
        elif self.rand_choi == '-': r = self.rand_int[0] - self.rand_int[1]
        else: r = self.rand_int[0] * self.rand_int[1]

        if str(r) == self.lineEdit.text():
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Welcom', 'Добро пожаловать!\nВеликий математик :)')
        else:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Error', 'Попробуйте еще раз.')

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Что такое reCAPTCHA вы можете ознакомиться: 
https://webscraping.pro/no-captcha-recaptcha-challenge/
и 
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro

А продемонстрировать работу можно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngine import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


class WebPage(QWebEnginePage):
    def userAgentForUrl(self, url):
        return super(WebPage, self).userAgentForUrl(url) + ' Chrome'


class Window(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setPage(WebPage(self))
        self.load(QUrl('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo'))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 600, 900)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: но вот есть вопрос. Есть ли ссылка на страницу где только прямоугольник каптчи и все, без форм?

Comment: @imapw_ найдите картинку или нарисуйте сами, и делайте с ней что хотите.